# Twitter Reverse Auth Without Requiring Local Account

Tags: ios, twitter, oauth

I am in need of acquiring a token for users using my app to post on their behalf.  I don't want to require them to have the Twitter account registered on their phone and would like to allow them to sign in if required.  The resources I've found so far require a local account.  Is there a library out there that will help facilitate this need?

With Facebook, it's a matter of providing a login button (provided) and native/web login is handled, but I end up with a token for re-use.

A few examples I've looked at so far...

- https://github.com/nst/STTwitter
- https://github.com/seancook/TWReverseAuthExample

Answer (score 0):

STTwitter doesn't require a local account.

You can login with Safari, [receive the access tokens through a callback](https://github.com/nst/STTwitter/blob/master/demo_ios/STTwitterDemoIOS/AppDelegate.m#L66), keep the access tokens and use them to post the reverse auth tokens.

The process is very similar to [this example](https://github.com/nst/STTwitter#reverse-authentication). You just don't use `twitterAPIOSWithFirstAccount` but the account used to login through Safari instead. See the [iOS demo](https://github.com/nst/STTwitter/blob/master/demo_ios/STTwitterDemoIOS/ViewController.m#L53) for this.